# Plugin generate a CV page

Tags: joomla-2.5, plugin, user

Is there any plugin that gives the admin the right to **create an user** and the system **generate a page contains the fields : photo, informations about the user etc (like a CV page)**, and this informations **can be filled by the user** created earlier ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few types of extensions that could be used although you may need to upgrade to Joomla 3.x to take advantage of the latest extensions.

**Content Construction Kit (CCK)**

Example: [FieldsAttach](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/fieldsattach), [Fields and Filters](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/fields-and-filters)

See http://extensions.joomla.org/category/authoring-a-content/content-construction for more ideas.

**Forms Extension**

Examples: [ChronoForms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/chronoforms), [RSForm](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/rsform-pro)

See http://extensions.joomla.org/category/contacts-and-feedback/forms for more ideas.

**Profile Extension**

Example: [Easy Profile](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/user-management/easy-profile), [Joom Profile](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/user-management/joom-profile)

See http://extensions.joomla.org/category/clients-a-communities/user-management for more ideas.